# WebSocket Python Server Send and Receive out of sync

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am in the process of making a `WebSocket` Server as a Python script to set up bi-directional data between this and a client. I have spent a lot of time getting to this point since I found out that I need the server to be multi threaded and to use queues for the send and receive data. Of course I am sure their are other ways to approach this but I have this working some what.

The problem I found, when I initially start the server, and then the client. I found I need the client to send something initially to the server to get communication going. Within in the `main()` of the server I am sending to the client a specific message in which I want it to return a specific response. This seems to get out of sync since it seems I only have one callback that processes the websocket data.

```
ws_server = websockets.serve(**server_data**, 'localhost', PORT, ping_interval=None, 
ping_timeout=None)
```

I don't know enough about the `asyncio` library to put in further logic to essentially have a send callback and a receive call back on only one `Websocket` connection I have full duplex communication but its out of sync, I also found I had to add a sleep in the server_data function which is slower than the sleep I added in the main to get this to work to this point.

Any suggestion sure would be appreciated !!!!

'''
ServerWebSocketThread.py

```
import websockets
import threading
import asyncio
import time

import collections

PORT = 7890

receiveMessageQueue = collections.deque()
sendMessageQueue = collections.deque()

async def server_data(websocket, path):
    print("A client just connected\n")
    datain = ''
    async for data in websocket:
        #async for outdata in websocket:
        if len(sendMessageQueue) > 0:
            print("SEND OUT DATA")
            await websocket.send(sendMessageQueue.popleft())
                
        # Receive in data and put into queue
        if len(data) > 0: 
            receiveMessageQueue.append(str(data))
            datain = receiveMessageQueue.popleft()
            print("Received data Pop off the queue = ", datain)

        # filter on a specific received message
        if datain == "SM_OFF":
            print("Received data Pop off the SM_OFF")
        elif datain == "SM_ON":
            print("Received data Pop off the SM_ON")
            # clear queue
        receiveMessageQueue.clear()
              
        await asyncio.sleep(10)


def server_callback():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    ws_server = websockets.serve(server_data, 'localhost', PORT, ping_interval=None, ping_timeout=None)
    loop.run_until_complete(ws_server)
 
    loop.run_forever() 
    #loop.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #allowInput = False
    # daemon server thread:
    server = threading.Thread(target=server_callback, daemon=True)
    server.start()
    print("Server listening on Port " + str(PORT))

    # Send out data
    while True:
       
        # send out some data see if it look good
        myMessageOut = "Mode_status_off"
        #myMessageOut = input('(server)type anything and click enter... ')
        sendMessageQueue.append(str(myMessageOut))
        time.sleep(5)

        myMessageOut = "Mode_status_on"
        sendMessageQueue.append(str(myMessageOut))
        time.sleep(5)
```

'''

'''Client.py
from websockets import connect
import asyncio
import sys
import time

```
# The main function that will handle connection and communication 
# with the server

MessageIn = ""
MessageOut = ""


class ClientWebSocketClass:
    def __init__(self, URL):
        self.URL = URL
        self.conn = None
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def sendout(self, message):
        return self.loop.run_until_complete(self.send(message))
       
    def receivein(self):
        return  self.loop.run_until_complete(self.receive())
   
    async def send(self, message):
        if self.conn == None:
            #self.conn = await connect(self.URL)
            self.conn = await connect(self.URL, ping_interval=None, ping_timeout=None)
        await self.conn.send(message)

    async def receive(self):
        return await self.conn.recv()

    def ping(self):
        return self.loop.run_until_complete(self._ping())

    async def _ping(self):
        await self.send("Hello World ITS CLIENT")
        return await self.receive()

def IvvSeq():
    # Class instance
    test = ClientWebSocketClass("ws://127.0.0.1:7890")
    
    MessageOut = ('This is from Client Initially.')
    test.sendout(MessageOut)

    while True:
        # Receive in a message
        MessageIn = test.receivein()
        
        #print("Received from Server ->", MessageIn)
        if MessageIn == "Mode_status_off":
            print("Received from Server Mode Status ->", "Mode_status_off")
            test.sendout("SM_OFF")
        elif MessageIn == "Mode_status_on":
            print("Received from Server Mode Status ->", "Mode_status_on")
            test.sendout("SM_ON")
        
        #print("Received from Server ->", MessageIn)
        time.sleep(1)
```

'''[image]